# Another good chess problem

Tags: problems

```
[Title "The Chess Monthly, 11/1860, Helpmate In 3 Moves (Version)"] 
[FEN "6R1/7q/8/5k2/3K1B2/8/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
[startflipped ""]
```

Now, in this chess problem by Samuel Loyd, both sides work together for a checkmate.  If Black is to move first, how can White give mate in 3 with Black's cooperation?

Answer (score 1):

Nice one:

> 1 Kf6 Ra8! 2 Kg7 Bb8 3 Kh8 Be5#!  ("Indian theme")